# Node.js - Express: Weird local paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is so weird how my local paths work. Like for example here is what my hierarchy looks like:

> public > css > bootstrap.css
>
> public > js > bootstrap.js
>
> templates > layout > page.ejs (default template for any page)
>
> templates > index.ejs and other .ejs templates

So inside of my page.ejs are my styling and scripting links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

And it works for my index.js for some reason. Whenever I go on to the website and I check the source, click on the links, all found and good. Whenever the same happens with my example.ejs file - these links are not found since it is being called from the /players/ directory in the source.

So for example a call for those files from the '/' page looks like:

```
GET /css/bootstrap.css 304 3.155 ms - -
GET /js/jquery.js 304 3.748 ms - -
GET /js/bootstrap.js 304 3.714 ms - -
```

But the call for the same file from the same template from /players/ is called like this:

```
GET /players/css/bootstrap.css 404 1.436 ms - 38
GET /players/js/jquery.js 404 1.197 ms - 33
GET /players/js/bootstrap.js 404 1.151 ms - 36
```

And obviously they are with tag 404 since they were not found. So my question is:

> How do I work with all of my paths?

I have tried absolute paths to those files - still not found. I have tried of think of some kind of dynamic script but I'm still not sure how it works.

For some reason it adds its own path to the files and not uses the path of the template... Ugh, I don't even know how to explain it but I think you get the idea. I think the "public" directory is tied to the routes so that's why I don't need to include it to the files that are requested from the index page but what about any other files?

Thank you and sorry for a lame question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Should be this:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Otherwise the browser will include the scripts relative to the current URL.

Comment: I could have swore I did that... But anyway, silly me, thank you!